# how to loop setTimeOut function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new on javascript and jquery , i create some function on this fiddle and it only run once, how to loop this function ??

```
    $(document).ready(function()  // function
    { 

     $('.box').css({visibility:'hidden'});

      setTimeout( function(){
        $('.box-1').css({visibility:'visible'});  
       },300);
      setTimeout( function(){
        $('.box-2').css({visibility:'visible'}); 
     },600);
     setTimeout( function(){
       $('.box-3').css({visibility:'visible'}); 
    },900);  
    setTimeout( function(){
      $('.box').fadeOut('slow'); 
   },1300);  
})
```

fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/dzh5dgcf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a setInterval()

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function animate() {
        $('.box').css({
            visibility: 'hidden',
            display: ''
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.box-1').css({
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
        }, 300);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.box-2').css({
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
        }, 600);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.box-3').css({
                visibility: 'visible'
            });
        }, 900);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.box').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 1300);
    }
    animate()
    setInterval(animate, 1800)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4jhazwma/)